# PHP code is rendered as text

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to run php files.

I installed Php 7 on it using:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html
sudo apt install php
sudo apt install apache2
```

I created a php file (e.g. `test.php`) in `/var/www/html`. I can access it in the browser (e.g. `http://localhost/test.php`). Instead of executing the `<?php ... ?>` code, it is displayed as plain text:

I tried to turn `short_open_tag` to `On`. So I edited the `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` and enabled it.

Then I ran `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`. This didn't make any change in the browser. The php code is still displayed as plain text.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should configure apache for work with php-fpm. For example manual for Ubuntu: https://www.howtoforge.com/using-php5-fpm-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts

Comment: did you install the php plugin for apache? `php` by ytself may not do that. it'd just install the cli version of php.

Comment: @newman Hmm, that looks obsolete... I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @MarcB When using Ubuntu 15.10, this worked just perfectly. The only difference it was the php version (and maybe the apache version)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't install apache properly, doing an apt-get on apache2 does not install everything.

what @newman stated is correct you can follow that guide, or here is a digitalocean link that is usuable for production server (since you would do this on a droplet). Note this is full stack LAMP, which I would assume you would get to eventually when you want to dab with mysql

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I ran `sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt`–but right after doing that, the problem wasn't solved. I saved again the `php.ini` file (without changing anything in it) and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @IonicăBizău when you install something in php.ini you need to restart php service